# How to make the animation smoother through code in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

How do we do the smooth animation.
I have the code as below.

```
ThicknessAnimation anima = 
    new ThicknessAnimation(new Thickness(0), new Thickness(0, 25, 0, 0), 
        new Duration(new TimeSpan(0, 0, seconds)), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);                  

pdRod.BeginAnimation(Border.MarginProperty, anima);
```

Its working, but not smooth enough.
How to do it smooth?

Thanks,

Comment: Researching I found this: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q454031/wpf-modify-built-in-animations-thread-priority
It worked wonders for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To do this in code, you would use the [`Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(Timeline,int?)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.setdesiredframerate.aspx) method, like this:

```
ThicknessAnimation anim = ...;
Timeline.SetDesiredFrameRate(anim, 60); // 60 FPS
```

Passing `null` for the second argument tells the system to control the frame rate.

Comment: For me setting `Timeline.DesiredFrameRate` on `Animation` didn't work. I had to set it on my `Storyboard` instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `StoryBoard`, use `Timeline.DesiredFrameRate` attached property.

Answer (score 2):

Try to adjust the attached property `Timeline.DesiredFrameRate` to your needs. An higher framerate will reduce the tearing you might see.

Comment: Thanks,
but
How to set Timeline.DesiredFrameRate for an animaition object/Frameorkelement object. In the above example , how to set ?